# The modal popup is not showing up

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]Am working on my final year project i need to have grid-view with model popup but whenever i click add button is not working. can anybody help me, i tried so many times and nothing is working stuck for 5 hrs.below is my html and back end code.Thanks. Nothing shows up when i click the button.

i really appreciate your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  
     <!----Required Head met tags ---->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!----The Title ---->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" /> 
    
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>  


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <div style="width: 90%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; text-align: center">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Manage Users </h3>
            
            <!-- Placing GridView in UpdatePanel-->
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCrudGrid" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="940px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
                        DataKeyNames="Id" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info"
                                ButtonType="Button" Text="Detail" HeaderText="Detailed View">
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info"
                                ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Record">
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="deleteRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info"
                                ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete Record">
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserType" HeaderText="UserType" />
                            
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Record" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
           
            <div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h3 id="editModalLabel">Edit Record</h3>
                </div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username : 
                            <asp:Label ID="tbUsername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Password : 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" Width="193px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" style="margin-left: 1px" Width="131px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Address:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAddress" runat="server" Width="148px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>UserType:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbUserType" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          
         
        </div>


        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2018 E-Bus ticketing system &middot; <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a> &middot; <a href="#">Update Schedule</a> &middot; <a href="#">Manage Users</a> &middot; <a href="#">Upload Tickets</a></p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to homeworkoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger via data-attribute i.e.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  // ...html
</div>
```

or using jQuery i.e.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show') //Open
```

[More details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods)

Comment: Where should i add $('#myModal').modal('show') //Open. please

Comment: It depends how you want to. You might bind with click event handler ( i.e. onclick = "doSomething()")  
    doSomething(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }